# Umlauts in SharePoint SendMail Utility

Tags: email, sharepoint, character-encoding

I have a WebService which sends an E-Mail via SPUtility.SendEmail-Method. Now my problem is, that I need to get the umlauts working. My code so far:

```
 StringDictionary headers = new StringDictionary();
 headers.Add("to",to);
 headers.Add("subject","äöü?");
 headers.Add("charset", "ISO-8859-1");
 headers.Add("content-type", "text/html");

 System.Text.StringBuilder strMessage = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
 strMessage.Append("ääääöööüüüü");

 SPUtility.SendEmail(SPContext.Current.Web, headers, strMessage.ToString());
```

I also tried to use UTF-8, but still the message I receive looks like this:
Subject: äöu?  (this works)
Body: C$C$C$C$C6C6C6C

I need to know how to make umlauts in the message-body possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it has to do with the charset settings.
You can check them in:

Central Administration -> System Settings -> Configure outgoing e-mail settings

You can set it to UTF-8 there.